# How do I set a composite primary key for a database in clickhouse?

Tags: composite-primary-key, clickhouse

For example my schema is

```
host : String,
timestamp : Date,
comment: String
```

I want my primary key to be host, timestamp.

Comment: ClickHouse has a number of "table engines". Not all engines support composite primary keys. An example of one which does is the MergeTree family of engines: https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/operations/table_engines/mergetree/

Comment: Yeah I saw that. Could you please give me an example using the same schema.

Answer (score 3):

```
create table data(host String, timestamp Date, comment String) 
engine MergeTree order by (host, timestamp);
```

## Update

The `MergeTree`'s primary key isn't the same as RDMBS ones in that it doesn't guarantee uniqueness. In order to achieve that, you can look into these two variants instead.

https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/operations/table_engines/replacingmergetree/

https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/operations/table_engines/collapsingmergetree/

Comment: You could have added line break to your example as the most interesting part is behind horizontal scroll.

Comment: This does not work. If i do ` insert into data values('12131','2018-12-16', 'hello')` and this insert the same values again then it accepts both